# Google Play app searching filter

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, android-permissions

I found Google Keep from the Google Play on my device.
However, after reinstalling the Android system, I can not find Google keep from the Google Play and it shows that "Your device is not compatible with this version"

I am very confused for this searching result while the same device ran well with this app before.

I can understand there are several ways to install this app on my device again.

A couple of questions confuse me..

1. How can I check the features that this app may change in the new version? This may cause the reason why I can not find it in the Google Play.
2. Will that be any possibility to modify my device source code in order to find this app on the Google Play in my device?

Thanks

---

I just found that shouldnt the permission(feature) issue because I can find and install other apps which require more permissions than Google Keep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The permissions that have anything to do with hardware are:

- record audio (needs microphone)
- precise location (GPS)
- control vibration

If your phone has these features and runs Android 4.0 and up, it should be compatible.

I see two possible reasons:

1. After reinstalling you have an older version of Android. If this is the case, check for updates and after updating it should work
2. Your device model may have been blacklisted because of compatibility issues. In this case, Google may find a solution in the future and Keep will become available.

You can install Keep anyway, sideloading it. You just have to download the .apk from somewhere (Google it and be careful for malware).

Comment: First of all, thanks for the reply.

1. The device runs with Android 4.2.2 and I am sure all permissions are compatible with my device. (Because I can install other Google apps with the more permissions than keep as I mentioned before)

2. I guess this is the case.....

Yes, I have downloaded the apk and instlled it onto my device. My intention is to know the detail part of why it just doesnt work on my device.

Comment: The reason why I can not find the app because my device doesnt have an necessary hardware feature. After adding the feature and re-build the image, the app shows up in my Google play.

Comment: So you were using a custom ROM... That explains it. Anyway, it's nice to hear you've solved it.